# htaccess maximum number lines for perfomance considerations

Tags: .htaccess

As a result of merging several sites together, I have a couple of thousand pages that need to be redirected. I cannot use wildcards as they are specific pages, so they will all be the form of:

```
Redirect 301 /old_page.html http://www.example.com/new_page.html
```

Is there a recommendation on how many lines can be in the .htaccess file before it starts to become a performance issue?  I'm sure it depends somewhat on the apache configuration, system memory, etc. but I'm trying to get an estimate.  Is 2,000 lines too long, or should it be 200, or is 20,000 okay?

Comment: are they all that simple ? regex will be much better if so

Comment: At that number it may be better to redirect to a site directory/map. Yeah you may loose some SEO, but SEO < your sanity

Comment: they are not all that simple. They are all quite long and complicated, such that regex cannot be used. For example, it could be something like: /fancy_new_blue_widgets_with_glossy_finish.html http://www.newsite.com/All_Widgets.html

Answer (score 0):

> I have a couple of thousand pages that need to be redirected. I cannot use wildcards as they are specific pages, so they will all be the form of:
>
> `Redirect 301 /old_page.html http://www.site.com/new_page.html`

Nope, don't do that.

Redirect everything (expect maybe static ressources like js, css, images, ... that have not changed) for that no current content can be found to a script instead - and have that look up the new URL corresponding to the old one requested, and then does a redirect with a `Location` header.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that I have a custom 404 page, which itself is a script?  And if the script finds a better match, it does a 301 redirect, otherwise it redirects to a static 404 page?

Comment: Not exactly, using `ErrorDocument 404` would mean lots of 404 error messages in your server's log files. Use mod_rewrite (or the `FallbackResource` directive if on an apache >= 2.2.16, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) to call that script, and have it answer with a 404 or 410 HTTP response code and message for the user if it does not find a new URL for the old one.

Comment: FallbackResource was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, I just didn't know what it was called. I just removed 6000 lines from my htaccess file. Thanks!